# how do you use soapsms php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
 use SoapClient;
 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

try {
    $client =  new \SoapClient("http://ippanel.com/class/sms/wsdlservice/server.php?wsdl");
    $user = "xxxxxxx";
    $pass = "xxxxxx";
    $fromNum = "3000505";
    $toNum = "xxxxxxx";
    $messageContent = 'this is my  test';
    $op  = "send";
    //If you want to send in the future  ==> $time = '2016-07-30' //$time = '2022-07-31 6:02:00'
//  $time = '2022-07-31 6:01:00';
    $client->SendSMS($fromNum,$toNum,$messageContent,$user,$pass,$op);
    //echo $status;
} catch (SoapFault $ex) {
    echo $ex->faultstring;
}
```

i get result of above code but when i use this code in laravel it dosen't work.do i change code in laravel?how do i change it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you use `ippanel` for your SMS provider, use `Restful` for sending and handling SMS with its document for web service.

It's much easier and better to work with that.

Comment: hi.i get result of above code.but now when i use that in laravel,it dosn't work. @amir-abouei

Comment: don't work with soap or rest? If you have any errors, send your errors here to check them.